# Use a bat to execute a cmd (say git) as though in another folder without cd

Tags: windows, command-line, git, batch-file

I have a windows BAT script that does the following:

```
call git reset --hard
call git clean --force
```

This works, but I really want to execute it within the context of another folder, something like (this doesn't work):

```
call ../git reset --hard
call ../git clean --force
```

How can I do this? I don't want to use 'cd' for a number of reasons, not least because it seems to break the execution change (only one git command runs).

Answer (score 1):

Not surprising your second example doesn't work, because `git` is a global command (assuming you installed it that way).  Doing `../git` is looking for an executable named `git` one folder back (I would assume in Windows it is looking for git.exe or git.bat there or something similar).

Instead, `git` provides an option for `--git-dir=<path>` (as per the man page).

```
--git-dir=<path>
    Set the path to the repository. This can also be controlled by
    setting the GIT_DIR environment variable. It can be an absolute
    path or relative path to current working directory.
```

So assuming it works in windows as it does in Linux, you would probably want:

```
call git reset --hard --git-dir=../otherproject/
call git clean --force --git-dir=../otherproject/
```

Answer (score 0):

Update:

--git-dir=
Set the path to the repository (".git" directory).This can also be controlled by setting the GIT_DIR environment variable. It can be an absolute path or relative path to current working directory.

So for the OP example :

```
call git reset --hard --git-dir=../otherproject/.git
call git clean --force --git-dir=../otherproject/.git
```